# Sending background mail using activation.jar,additional.jar and mail.jar in android

Tags: java, android, email, jar, email-attachments

I have my project working with the below codes but the thing is that i also want to send the image which i have captured from my camera also which i am able to save in the card.....in the below code i just click on the image button and the message is send to the email id which i have defined but i also want to send the image which i am not able to do..

**1.)MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;
    Activity context;
    Preview preview;
    Camera camera;
    Button exitButton;
    ImageView fotoButton;
    LinearLayout progressLayout;
    String path = "/sdcard/cc/images/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context=this;

        fotoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto);
        exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_photo);
        progressLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);

        preview = new Preview(this,
                (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.KutCameraFragment));
        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        frame.addView(preview);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);




        fotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    takeFocusedPicture();
                    String fromEmail = "email_id@gmail.com";
                String fromPassword = "xxxx";
                String toEmails = "email_id@gmail.com";
                String adminEmail = "email_id@gmail.com";
                String emailSubject = "xxxx";
                String adminSubject = "xxxx";
                String emailBody = "xxxx";
                String adminBody = "xxxx";
                new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this).execute(fromEmail,
                        fromPassword, toEmails, emailSubject, emailBody,path);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                exitButton.setClickable(false);
                fotoButton.setClickable(false);
                progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(camera==null){
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.startPreview();
            camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
                public void onError(int error, Camera mcamera) {

                    camera.release();
                    camera = Camera.open();
                    Log.d("Camera died", "error camera");

                }
            });
        }
        if (camera != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(context,
                        CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        }
    }

    private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId,
            android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }



    Camera.AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {

            try{
                camera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null, jpegCallback);

            }catch(Exception e){

            }

        }
    };

    Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    public void takeFocusedPicture() {
        camera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);

    }

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            File videoDirectory = new File(path);

            if (!videoDirectory.exists()) {
                videoDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                // Write to SD Card
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(path + c.getTime().getSeconds() + ".jpg");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + outStream,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 




                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }


            Bitmap realImage;
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;

            options.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared

            options.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future


            realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length,options);
            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(path + c.getTime().getSeconds()
                        + ".jpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Log.d("EXIF value",
                        exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
                if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            image.setImageBitmap(realImage);



            fotoButton.setClickable(true);
            camera.startPreview();
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            exitButton.setClickable(true);

        }
    };

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }

}
```

**2.)GMail.java**

```
public class GMail {

    final String emailPort = "587";// gmail's smtp port
    final String smtpAuth = "true";
    final String starttls = "true";
    final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

    String fromEmail;
    String fromPassword;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    String toEmailList;
    String emailSubject;
    String emailBody;
    String path;
    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public GMail() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
            String toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody,String path) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
        this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
        this.path = path;

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
        Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
    }

    public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));

            Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmailList);
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(toEmailList));


        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(path);
        Log.i("sourcesourcesourcesourcesource" +path, path);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
       messageBodyPart.setFileName("attachmentName");
        messageBodyPart.setText(emailBody);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        emailMessage.setContent(multipart);


        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
        // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
        Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
        return emailMessage;
    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
        Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");

    }


}
```

**3.)SendMailTask.java**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

        private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
        private Activity sendMailActivity;

        public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
            sendMailActivity = activity;

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
            statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
            statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
            statusDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
            try {
                Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
                publishProgress("Processing input....");
                GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                        args[1].toString(),  args[2].toString(), args[3].toString(),
                        args[4].toString(), args[5].toString());
                publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
                androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
                publishProgress("Sending email....");
                androidEmail.sendEmail();
                publishProgress("Email Sent.");
                Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");

              //  Config.mailSuccess="1";


            } catch (Exception e) {
                publishProgress(e.getMessage());
                Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            statusDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }
```

Mail is sending successfully on camera click but i am not able to attach the image.

Comment: [Sending mail attachment using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16117365/4290096)

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ where should i do the proper changes in the code

Comment: restructure your GMail.java class by referring the accepted answer from the above link , on camera click get the image file(it's path) pass it to the GMail constructor. If you get stuck somewhere comeback with a specific question.

Comment: @shreya http://stackoverflow.com/a/16117448/3514144 is suggested by javY

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27032266/3035416

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ there is no accepted  answer in the link you provided http://stackoverflow.com/q/16117365/4290096

Comment: @ShreyaSrivastava I meant the top answer([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16117448/4290096)). Sorry.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ if i say truth i am unable to do that in the above code of mine  struggling from past 2 hours :(

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595170/get-the-file-path-of-the-image-clicked-from-surfaceview-camera?noredirect=1#comment58881834_35595170)

Comment: @ShreyaSrivastava , saw that yesterday . I am not good with Android.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ ok ..Never mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your GMail class , **do necessary changes for your implementation**.

```
public class GMail {

    final String emailPort = "587";
    final String smtpAuth = "true";
    final String starttls = "true";
    final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

    String fromEmail;
    String fromPassword;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    String toEmailList;
    String emailSubject;
    String emailBody;
    String path;
    String attachmentName;
    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public GMail() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
            String toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody, String path, String attachmentName) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
        this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
        this.path = path;
        this.attachmentName = attachmentName;

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);

    }

    public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));

    Log.i("GMail", "toEmail: " + toEmailList);
    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(toEmailList));

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(path);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     textBodyPart.setText(emailBody);
     multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);

    emailMessage.setContent(multipart);
        Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
        return emailMessage;
    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
        Log.i("GMail", "allrecipients: " + emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");

    }

}
```

---

*I have tested this code with port 465 and PasswordAuthentication*

Comment: only mail is going...no image attachment is being send to email id

Comment: log cat is showing -- I/SendMailTask(28448): About to instantiate GMail...
I/GMail(28448): Mail server properties set.
I/GMail(28448): toEmail: xxx@gmail.com
I/image path/sdcard/cc/images/4.jpg(28448): path/sdcard/cc/images/4.jpg
I/GMail(28448): Email Message created.
D/EXIF value(28448): 1
I/GMail(28448): allrecipients: [Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@42f6ac68
I/GMail(28448): Email sent successfully.
I/SendMailTask(28448): Mail Sent.

Comment: @ShreyaSrivastava , `emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");` was the issue . I have updated the answer.

Comment: log cat is showing error ....avax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
nested exception is:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/cc/images: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
at com.vv.GMail.sendEmail(GMail.java:96)
at com.vv.SendMailTask.doInBackground(SendMailTask.java:42)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)

Comment: path means , full path, eg : `/home/user/Downloads/google.jpg` , you should  pass an image's path , not folder path

Comment: ok i saw it mailing me the the pre-defined image...but in the MainActivity.java i am capturing image and then saving in sdcard dynamically ...it should mail the dynammic clicked image not the predefined one which is already saved.

Comment: If you don't know how to get the dynamic path ,you can ask a different question like ' How to get captured images path in Android after camera click' .

Comment: Ok thanx for your help a lot .

Comment: great, you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9095148/4290096) for getting image path , if it does not help you ask a new question.